# catkin_make error: no such file or directory from custom library

Tags: c++, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!
I created my own library and catkin is telling me that the header doesn't exist. Currently i am working on ubuntu 14.04 and ROSIndigo.

This is what my compiler tells me: .../signbot_plugins/src/signbot_core.cpp:1: error: signbot_plugins/classtradutor.h: No such file or directory

Here's my package order:

```
signbot_plugins/
      include/
            signbot_plugins/
                          classtranslator.h
       msg/
       src/
            classtranslator.cpp
            signbot_core.cpp
     CMakeLists.txt
     package.xml
```

Heres my CMakeList.txt:

```
 cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)

 project(signbot_plugins)

  find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  message_generation
  roscpp
  trajectory_msgs)
  
   catkin_package(
   INCLUDE_DIRS include
   LIBRARIES signbot_plugins 
   CATKIN_DEPENDS
       message_runtime
       roscpp
        trajectory_msgs
    #  DEPENDS system_lib
  )

   include_directories(
   include
   ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
  )

 add_library(classtranslator src/classtranslator.cpp)
 add_dependencies(classtranslator ${${PROJECT_NAME}_EXPORTED_TARGETS} ${catkin_EXPORTED_TARGETS})

 target_link_libraries(classtranslator ${catkin_LIBRARIES})


 add_executable(signbot_core_node src/signbot_core.cpp)
 add_dependencies(signbot_core_node signbot_core_cpp)
 target_link_libraries(signbot_core_node classtranslator ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
```

Can anyone help me?
Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/270151/catkin_make-error:-no-such-file-or-directory-from-custom-library/) by [FábioBarbosa](https://answers.ros.org/users/29070/f%C3%A1biobarbosa/) on ROS Answers with karma: 137 on 2017-09-04

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

From this:

> Here's my package order:

> ```
> signbot_plugins/
> ```

```
      include/
            signbot_plugins/
                          classtranslator.h
      ...
```

and this:

> This is what my compiler tells me:

> ```
> .../signbot_plugins/src/signbot_core.cpp:1: error: signbot_plugins/classtradutor.h: No such file or directory
> ```

I think the problem is that you try to `#include` a file called `classtradutor.h`, but you have an actual file called `classtranslator.h`.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-09-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-09-04**:
Note that this is not a ROS problem.

**Comment by [FábioBarbosa](https://answers.ros.org/users/29070/f%C3%A1biobarbosa/) on 2017-09-04**:
Thanks for seeing that. my bad! changed the name of the class, but forgot to change the file name too.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-09-04**:
No problem. Good to hear that solved it.